# Iterate through table row images and click on hyperlink

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with multiple rows ( `tr`) that contains multiple cells ( `td` )

one of the cells contains an image hyperlink

I would link to iterate through the table rows and click on every cell containing the image of each row, using selenium.

for example, this is one of my tables:

```
<table class="thetable" cellspacing="1" >

        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>

           <tr class="visibleRow">


               <td class="Item"></td>
               <td class="modified" style="color: gray;"></td>
               <td class="imageHyperlink">
                  <a href="#" role="button" title="Edit the item">
                       <img src="web/service/editRow.gif" />

                  </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="visibleRow"></tr>

            <tr class="anotherow" style="display: none;"></tr>

            <tr class="visibleRow"></tr>

            <tr class="editorRow" style="display: none;"></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

the only rows that I want to iterate through are the ones containing the class name `visibleRow`, and the only cells that need to be clicked on are the cells containing the class name `imageHyperlink`

I implemented a for loop that iterate through the rows with class visibleRow, store the cell class name inside cell variable. and click on the cell:

```
for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.visibleRow"):
    cell = row.find_elements_by_class_name("imageHyperlink")
    cell.click()
```

However I am getting this error as it seems the cell is not the clickable item:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `row.find_elements_by_class_name("imageHyperlink")` (note the plural name element**s**) returns a list, which in your case will have zero or one element. Adding a second level of iteration should fix the problem:

```
for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.visibleRow"):
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_class_name("imageHyperlink"):
        cell.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

The inner loop iterates over the children of the that have the class `imageHyperLink`; in your example, there will be either one of these (for the first visible row) or none (for the others). It then finds the first `<a>` child element and clicks on it.

Comment: Note that this fixed the error but does not click on the hyperlink of the image, I see it iterating through rows only. (I added the image tag in which I forgot to put). Any solution ?

Comment: Ah; I was working on the assumption that the hyperlink completely filled the `td`, and so clicking on the latter would work. I'll edit the code to click on the nested element.

Comment: Yeap I figured it out after I asked you the question. Thank you though now I know how to work with tags and sub tags